# The equality $\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was reading an [article](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf) and the author immediately states that the following identity is clear
 $$\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^2}.$$

I verified that $\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2}$, but I am having trouble seeing how it is obvious that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^2}$ equates as well.

I tried expanding terms, but it did not get me anywhere. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{\underset{n\,even}{n = 1}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{\underset{n\, odd}{n = 1}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}.$$

Comment: That makes it immediately clear. Thank you.